# Chrome extension to load a page and inject code

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to create a simple extension which will load a given page and inject code once the page has loaded.

I came up with the following, am I doing this the right way?

background.js

```
    chrome.tabs.getCurrent(function (tab) {
      chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, {url: "http://www.EXAMPLE.COM"});
    });

    chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId , info) {
        if (info.status == "complete") {
                 chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "content_script.js"});
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting [`chrome.tabs` documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-getCurrent) for `chrome.tabs.getCurrent`:

> Gets the tab that this script call is being made from. May be undefined if called from a non-tab context (**for example: a background page** or popup view).

To grab the currently active tab, you should instead use `chrome.tabs.query`:

```
chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true}, function(tabs){
  // Do something with tabs[0]
});
```

Alternatively, if you're reacting to user input, like a click on the browser action, you're already supplied the current tab:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab){
  // "tab" is the current active tab
});
```

---

Instead of grabbing an already-open tab, you can simply create a new one (depends on what you're trying to achieve, of course):

```
chrome.tabs.create({url: "http://www.EXAMPLE.COM"});
```

---

Your listener will try to inject the content script into the current tab (you used `null`) whenever any tab finishes loading, not just the one you created. It's safer to do so from `create`/`update` callbacks, i.e.

```
chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, {url: "http://www.EXAMPLE.COM"}, function(tab){
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file: "content_script.js"});
});
```

Note: you don't have to worry that the page did not finish loading at this point. `executeScript` obeys the [`run_at` parameter](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#type-InjectDetails), which defaults to "sometime after DOM is loaded".